# How to create a preset for printing a workbook in MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, printing

I need to create a Default preset for 1-Click-Printing a workbook in MS Excel.

This includes predefining Sorting and Filtering values,

Adding text to top and bottom of the printed document,

And designing the desired margins to be printed.

Is it possible to create some sort of custom view file to use when printing the workbook?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this by customizing `book.xltx` (or `book.xlt` for older versions), as described in this pages:

- [Default Templates](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/default-templates.html) *Excel Easy*
- [Productivity 101: Setting Up Excel Default Formatting](http://www.vitalyst.com/2011/03/productivity-101-setting-up-excel-default-formatting/)

According to Microsoft support, Excel supports the *printing* aspect in templates.  Here are a few links which discuss this:

- *[Print a worksheet in landscape or portrait orientation](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Print-a-worksheet-in-landscape-or-portrait-orientation-342b8e2c-5c00-4819-a3f0-4e6503e7cbca)* includes this *[Create a template that uses landscape orientation by default](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Print-a-worksheet-in-landscape-or-portrait-orientation-342b8e2c-5c00-4819-a3f0-4e6503e7cbca#bm3)*
- *[Microsoft Excel 2013 Tutorial - 15 - Templates and Printing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OFZFAJZZunM)*  also covers the topic.

Comment: From what I understand in the mentioned pages, I think the default templates affect the view of the document and it's settings, 
Not the printing default features. Am I wrong?
What I'm trying to achieve is to create a file for 1-Click-Printing, With pre-selected values in table headers, hidden columns, etc.